# Apprehension in a solved problem from Feller

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-expectation

This one is a solved example from Feller.

> Spores of the Fungus are produced in chains of eight.The chain may
>   break into several parts into projectiles containing 1 to 8 pores.
>   Find the expected no. of doublets if all links have probability $p$ to
>   break.

If we assume $S$ to be the random variable which assumes the no. of doublets formed, then we need to evaluate $E[S]$. The maximum value $S$ can assume is $4$. However, Feller has expressed $S=S_1+S_2+S_3+S_4+S_5+S_6+S_7$ as there are $7$ different ways a doublet can be formed where $S_i \in \{0,1\}$. I'm unable to comprehend the equality of $S$ with $\sum S_i$ as they have different range with $S \in \{0,4\}$  and $\sum S_i \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.

Can someone explain the rationale behind it?

Comment: Would you mind providing brief explanations of what the $S_i$ represent, as well as what "doublets" and "links" are?  Without that information, this question is incomprehensible.

Comment: No cross-post please: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1432766/

Answer (score 2):

The $S_i$ are not independent.  For example, if $S_1 =1$, $S_2=0$.  The sum can never be above 4.  This does not mean that we can't discuss the sum of these variables and that sum is clearly equal to the total number of pairs.